# Reasoning with disjunction

Tags: dafny

This is not verified by Dafny:

```
assert forall p,q,p',q' :: (p==>p' && q==>q') ==> (p||q ==> p'||q') ;
```

And, more generally, I'm having trouble verifying calculations involving disjunction.

Comment: `||` and `&&` have higher parsing precedence than `==>`. Can you try putting parentheses around `p ==> p'` and `q ==> q'`?

Answer (score 0):

```
assert forall p,q,p',q' :: ((p==>p') && (q==>q')) ==> (p||q ==> p'||q') ;
```

Don't forget the parentheses around `==>`, otherwise your second condition is treated as `p ==> ((p' && q) ==> q')`